# Mutable Data Structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Which standard data structures in Java are mutable besides Collections?

Please correct me if I am wrong but I believe Collections like LinkedList, Set, etc... are mutable in java.

I can't seem to locate any info on this.

Comment: So, is the question about collections, or about other data structures? Shouldn't you rather ask yourself if a given data structure is mutable or not, rather than to try finding them all? And thus read the javadoc of that data structure to find out?

Comment: IMO the basic Collections such as List and Set are interfaces, i.e. abstract data types and not implementations, aka. data structures. However, all of them specify a mutable interface (there are add and remove methods). On the other hand, nothing is stopping implementations from throwing exceptions for the mutating operations, which is what `Collections.unmodifiableList` makes use of. I am not sure what you mean by "standard data structures".

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'data structure'. But as a starting point you could check the Javadoc and look at all implementations of 'Iterable' and 'Map'. This includes most normal data structures but a lot of other stuff that could be considered a data structure.